# Generate 2d points based on sample points with variance

Tags: python

I have a plot where I gather 10 points via mouseclick events on a 2d grid [-55 - 55, -35, 35]. After that I'm adding a label representing the 10 points and save it in a list.

Here is a sample entry of the result list:

```
<class 'list'>: [[-38.39, 20.3], [-38.25, 12.27], [-38.39, 5.0], [-38.96, -3.48], [-37.54, -15.61], [-26.33, -7.73], [-28.32, 3.03], [-26.47, 14.24], [-20.08, 15.15], [-18.38, -1.36], [1.0]]
```

Now I want to generate similar list entries based on the 10 sample points. The data should later serve as training data for a model to determine different formations of the 10 points.

I would appreciate tips for the generation of similar points within a certain degree of variance.

Comment: Do you just want to sample similar points in the radius of the mouseclicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily sample new positions by just adding a **random x/y value**. I've attached the results of this sampling method.

```
points = [[-38.39, 20.3], [-38.25, 12.27], [-38.39, 5.0], [-38.96, -3.48], [-37.54, -15.61], [-26.33, -7.73], [-28.32, 3.03], [-26.47, 14.24], [-20.08, 15.15], [-18.38, -1.36]]
newPoints = []
for point in points:
    singleSet = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        singleSet.append([point[0] + uniform(-0.5, 0.5), point[1] + uniform(-0.5, 0.5)])
    newPoints.append(singleSet)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension would work. I'll just make a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
point = [-38, 20.3]

[[a, b] for a in np.arange(point[0]-1, point[0]+1.2, 0.2) for b in np.arange(point[1]-1, point[1]+1.2, 0.2)]

Ouput:
[[-39.0, 19.3],
 [-39.0, 19.5],
 [-39.0, 19.7],
 [-39.0, 19.9],
 [-39.0, 20.099999999999998],
 [-39.0, 20.299999999999997],
 [-39.0, 20.499999999999996],
 [-39.0, 20.699999999999996],
 [-39.0, 20.899999999999995],
 [-39.0, 21.099999999999994],
 [-39.0, 21.299999999999994],
 [-38.8, 19.3],
 [-38.8, 19.5],
 [-38.8, 19.7],
 [-38.8, 19.9],
 [-38.8, 20.099999999999998],
 [-38.8, 20.299999999999997],
 [-38.8, 20.499999999999996],
 [-38.8, 20.699999999999996],
 [-38.8, 20.899999999999995], ...... etc
```

For the approximation problem 0.x9999999999999, you can just use `round(val, 3)`:

```
round(20.029999999999998, 3)
Out[182]: 20.03
```

To get back to the first point, you now just need to loop on your list, and every time generate a new set of points around.

```
new_set = list()
for p in point_list:
    new_set.append([[round(a,3), round(b,3)] for a in np.arange(p[0]-1, p[0]+1.2, 0.2) for b in np.arange(p[1]-1, p[1]+1.2, 0.2)])
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a list of coordinates `(x, y)` and a variance `var`. You could generate new coordinates in a random fashion like this:

`(x, y) --> (random(x-var, x+var), random(y-var, y+var))`